# Accordion Scroll issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like my accordion to scroll the page when opened.

Here is the code,

```
<button class="accordion">Services We Offer</button>
<div class="panel">
<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
acc[i].onclick = function() {
this.classList.toggle("active");
var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
if (panel.style.maxHeight){
  panel.style.maxHeight = null;
} else {
  panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
} 
}
}
</script>
<p>
<strong>PC Repairs</strong> - CCC Digital Solutions offers a PC repair 
service. Users can enquire about prices for PC repairs and get rough 
estimates on how much it will cost. Users will also find a FAQ guide on how 
to attempt to repair their PC themselves. Click <a href=   "pcRepairs.html" 
title="PC Repairs" target="_blank">HERE</a> to go to the PC Repairs page.
<br />
<br />
<strong>Digital Graphics</strong> - CCC Digital Solutions offers a Digital 
Graphics service. Users can enquire and get in contact about personal 
graphics to be made or they can view tutorials on how to make graphics and 
how to effectively use photoshop. Click <a href="digitalGraphics.html" 
title="Digital Graphics" target="_blank">HERE</a> to go to the Digital 
Graphics page.
<br />
<br />
<strong>Website Development</strong> - CCC Digital Solutions offers a 
Website Development service. Users can view this page to find prices for 
website development or they can find links to the W3Schools website which 
will teach them basic and advanced website development. Click <a 
href="websiteDevelopment.html" title="Website Development" 
target="_blank">HERE</a> to go to the Website Development page.
<br />
<br />
<strong>Website Maintenance</strong> - CCC Digital Solutions offers a 
Website Maintenance service. Users can view this page and find guides and 
tips on how to maintain a website that has been created. Click <a 
href="websiteMaintenance.html" title="Website Maintenance" 
target="_blank">HERE</a> to go to the Website Maintenance page.
<br />
<br />
<strong>Training Courses</strong> - CCC Digital Solutions offers a Training 
Courses service. Users can view this page and find out what courses are 
available and what each course will roughly cost. Click <a 
href="trainingCourses.html" title="Training Courses" 
target="_blank">HERE</a> to go to the Training Courses page.
</p>
</div>
```

Basically, I have a parallax image and when the user scrolls down the page the accordion shows. When the accordion is opened at the bottom of the page it overlaps the page and doesn't show the contents unless the user scrolls down.

I would like the accordion to automatically scroll the page so the user can see the contents.

---

CSS Code

```
.parallax { 
/* The image used */
background-image: url("images/collegecampus.jpg");

/* Set a specific height */
height: 660px;
width: auto;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 0;
padding-left: 0cm;
padding-right: 0cm;
border-left: 0;
margin: 0;

/* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}

/* Style the buttons that are used to open and close the accordion panel */
button.accordion {
background-color: #5e1969;
color: #ddd;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 18px;
width: 100%;
text-align: left;
border: none;
outline: none;
transition: 0.4s;
}

/* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active 
class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */
button.accordion.active {
background-color: #5e1969;
color: #ddd;
}

button.accordion:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
color: #5e1969;
}

div.panel {
padding: 0 18px;
background-color: white;
max-height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

button.accordion:after {
content: '\02795'; /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
font-size: 13px;
color: #777;
float: right;
margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
content: "\2796"; /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!   The code you've provided is not sufficient to reproduce the problem.  Can you please include your CSS as well (ideally in a SO code snippet -- hit `ctrl-M` or the icon with the angle brackets on it) so we can see the behavior in action?

Comment: I think a good start my be to take a look at bootstrap. http://getbootstrap.com/.  It makes a lot of your code easier and quicker to write.

Comment: @DanielBeck i have added the CSS code as requested